# Ambiguous Struct Constructors in D

Tags: constructor, struct, initialization, d, ambiguity

I'm having some trouble understanding how to deal with ambiguity of constructors in D.

```
struct mydta {
    int a = 2;
    int b = 3;

    this(int c) {
        a = c / 2;
        b = c * 2;
    }
    this(float c) {
        a = cast(int) c / 2;
        b = cast(int) c * 2;
    }

    static mydta afvec = mydta(4.3);
    static mydta aivec = mydta(5);
}
```

- `afvec` has the data values 2 and 8.
- `aivec` has the data values 5 and 3.

This means that `afvec` called `this(float c)` as expected from the syntax.

However `aivec` has done an assignment similar to `aivec.a = 5`.

I extrapolated on this to find that the following is legal in the above: `aivec = mydta(5, 4);` giving `aivec` the values 5 and 4 respectively.

Any ideas how to bypass this implicit initialization so I can access my constructor: `this(int c)`?

Comment: A float could also be 5 so it doesn't know which constructor to use. Try adding a cast to one of them.

Comment: That is not the problem, the problem is if I use an int, it calls some implicit initialization instead of the `this(int c)` constructor I want it to call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like a bug to me.

If you do this:

```
mydta foo = mydta(5);
writeln(foo.b);
```

You get `10` as expected. There were a lot of changes to CTFE for version 2.053, so something may have been broken as a result. Please post it as a bug at the [D issue tracking system](http://d.puremagic.com/issues/).

Comment: Your right, it only occurs for the static variable, and works in other situations. Thanks.